# Difference between 'setup' and 'setupSpec' when initialising a Spock stub?

Tags: spock, stub

I am confused about stub initialize in `setup()` and `setupSpec()`, demo:

```java
class SpockTestSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared Service service
    @Shared MsgClient msgClient
    @Shared QueryResult queryResult

    def setupSpec() {
        msgClient = Stub(MsgClient)
        queryResult = Stub(QueryResult)
        service = new Service(msgClient: msgClient)
    }

    def "test1"() {
        given:
        def msg = "hello world"
        def queryId = "abc123"

        queryResult.getQueryId() >> queryId
        msgClient.submitAsync(_) >> queryResult

        when:
        def resp = service.query(msg)

        then:
        resp.getMsg() == msg
        resp.getQueryId() == queryId
    }
}
```

It cannot work because the stub queryResult return `""`, which expect a queryId.
when I use a `setup()` it works well:

```java
class SpockTestSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared Service service
    @Shared MsgClient msgClient
    @Shared QueryResult queryResult

    def setup() {
        msgClient = Stub(MsgClient)
        queryResult = Stub(QueryResult)
        service = new Service(msgClient: msgClient)
    }

    def "test1"() {
        given:
        def msg = "hello world"
        def queryId = "abc123"

        queryResult.getQueryId() >> queryId
        msgClient.submitAsync(_) >> queryResult

        when:
        def resp = service.query(msg)

        then:
        resp.getMsg() == msg
        resp.getQueryId() == queryId
    }
}
```

What is the difference between init stub in `setup()` and `setupSpec()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask questions, providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is a test in two variations, but at least 3 classes used in the test are missing. So how is anyone supposed to know what they do? Besides, `QueryResult = Stub(QueryResult)` can only be an error, because you cannot assign a stub to a class instance. Probably you mean `queryResult = Stub(QueryResult)` with lower-case "q". Please do not post untested pseudo code, because it is like shooting yourself in the own foot, being unable to get answers if your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Next, please read the Spock manual. It nicely describes the difference between `setup()` and `setupSpec()` and also explains what `@Shared` fields are for. I think that `@Shared` is widely overused (and abused), and my impression is that your example code is no exception. Please explain why you think you need shared fields. I just see premature optimisation here and the big danger of context from one feature method bleeding over into the next one - if you even have more than one method, that is. But if you only have one, you do not need `@Shared` either, so what is the point?

Comment: @kriegaex sorry for my example, it's inexperienced. I've removed what I think the 'useless class'. I use `@shared` Because field used in `setupSpec()` must be shared, and what I want to know is why I can't init a stub in `setupSpec()`, while it's work in `setup()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a current limitation of Spock that you can't create usable `@Shared` mocks. Mocks are cheap to create so there is no reason to share them. It would introduce needless coupling between tests. As stated in this [issue](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1423#issuecomment-1032594145) there is a workaround, but I strongly advise against it.